# Do JONAH and similar organizations successfully help those with same-gender attractions?

Tags: sexuality, organizations, psych-mentalhealth

Wikipedia's article on [homosexuality and Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism_and_sexual_orientation) talks about Jewish [organizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism_and_sexual_orientation#Ex-gay_organizations) which aim to help people change.  The article mentions [JONAH](http://www.jonahweb.org/), an organization which works on "prevention, intervention, and healing of the underlying issues causing same-sex attractions".  The article also mentions [Atzat Nefesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atzat_Nefesh).

There also exist secular organizations, and Christian organizations, with similar goals.

Are these organizations successful at helping their clients?

I define "successful helping" quite broadly.  I define it to be the successful achievement of any of the following.

- Reducing clients' same-sex attractions.
- Curing clients' same-sex attractions.
- Helping bisexual clients with dating-related issues as they work towards [marriage](http://www.google.com/search?q=mixed-orientation+marriages).  (For example, the issue of when to tell one's date about one's sexual orientation.)
- Or helping with other problems that clients may have.  For example:

  - dysfunctional family relationships;
  - trust issues;
  - reclusiveness;
  - problems dealing with emotions such as sadness.

Please don't answer unless you cite sources.

Comment: Do you mean 'useful' in that they are trying to accomplish something good, or that they are successful at what they do?

Comment: Hakirah has been having a series of articles on SSA (same-sex attraction) in the Jewish community featuring discussion with R' S. Kaminetzky, the primary rabbinic endorser of JONAH (I think). The articles are all available [online](http://hakirah.org/). (Only the first two pages of the most recent article are available as of now.)

Comment: To the user who downvoted me:  Why the downvote?  Feel free to email me privately if you insist:  <tealhill at gmail.com>.

Comment: @tealhill Hello tealhill, welcome to Mi.Yodeya and thank you for this question! I'm glad to see you've registered your account, I hope you stick around and enjoy it!

Comment: Incidentally, people who downvote and don't leave comments are going to be very unlikely to email you. FWIW, I upvoted.

Comment: I'm sorry to be naggy, but you didn't pick one of my two suggestions. As it stands, I'm still not sure what you are asking: are you looking to evaluate if JONAH successfully can 'cure' gay individuals, or do you want to know if their aims are worthwhile? Is this question empirical or axiological?

Comment: @DoubleAA:  It was my mistake; I was slow to edit the question.  I have now edited it.  Is it completely clear now?

Comment: @tealhill Much better, thank you. It seems you were asking the empirical question.

Comment: Dear all:  Do you think I should specify the following in the question?  "Please don't answer unless you cite [reliable medical sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Identifying_reliable_sources#Medical_claims)."

Comment: @tealhill, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Because JONAH is not a scientific organisation, and has no consistent model underlying its therapies (which are really, it seems, based mostly on outdated stereotypes of masculinity and femininity), they occasionally contradict themselves, or even outright lie, as recently noted by [Truth Wins Out](http://www.truthwinsout.org/blog/2012/09/29888/). Given that JONAH are proven liars, I doubt there's much more you need to know.

Comment: @TRiG:  I'm asking about the entire class of organizations, not only about JONAH.  Also, the blog post you cite has failed to convince me of any lie going on.  Gay guys who work out are trying to feel more masculine.  The therapist who advised his client to go work out was also trying to help his client feel more masculine.  I don't see any lie there.

Comment: You can find more informed and impartial answers here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/564/6962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to shed light on the important issue of whether homosexuals can "change" to become the heterosexuals that Hashem intended them to be.  As Co-Director of JONAH, I chose to submit the paragraphs shown below which were written by a therapist who is not associated with JONAH, but who has counseled men and women with unwanted same-sex attractions (SSA) for decades. There is not a shred of evidence that anyone is born gay and those who are unhappy being gay or lesbian have been walking away from homosexuality throughout history.  Gay activists, who started out to help those with SSA, have become as irrational and damaging as those who previously discriminated against homosexuals in the past. Although feeling SSA is not a choice, a person has the right to choose whether to attempt to deal with these feelings or not, and those who attempt to ban all counseling for unwanted SSA have become malicious agitators against free choice.

---

http://drsorotzkin.com/light_on_gay_issue.html:

> Shedding Light on the Gay Issue
>
> Many people find it difficult to believe that there is not a shred of credible scientific evidence for the existence of the "gay gene," since it flies in the face of what is presented as fact in our culture. There have been a few attempts by self identified gay scientists to present evidence of genetic contributions to homosexuality, but these endeavors have never withstood scientific scrutiny, a point that gay activist researchers now concede.1 Most people are unaware of the fact that gay rights advocates have often written in their internal documents that it advances their agenda to popularize the concept of a "gay gene" (regardless of the lack of scientific evidence).2
>
> The fact that overcoming SSA is indeed difficult and is often only achieved imperfectly is also cited as evidence of the unchangeable nature of sexual orientation thus making the apparent change not authentic. This claim is absurd! All psychological problems are difficult to change. Is it easy to help someone improve his self-esteem? Or to develop confidence? Or to overcome years of abuse? When the person makes progress, do we belittle his progress because he is still struggling? And if he improves with his issue 90%, do we not see this as a tremendous success even though vestiges of his problem remain? Why is the treatment of SSA held to such ridiculous and illogical and dramatically different standards than other areas of psychotherapy? Only because of a political agenda, it seems.

Comment: Elaine Silodor Berk, welcome to the site, and thanks for your perspective. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. This answer is valuable only to the extent it cites that essay, so editing in information on its author's credentials would be valuable. Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1533), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Not even one shred of evidence? Science has discovered more things since 2005 http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,316316,00.html

Comment: @zaq The article you cite finishes by saying that they have no idea if the same thing applies to humans.

Comment: That's the case with any animal-study, human trials are always necessary to generalize the findings. However, to say there's "not a shred of evidence" that homosexuality is genetic sounds very biased when there are studies that show some evidence. Currently the jury is out on whether it's genetic, biological or environmental. One could just as accurately say there is not one shred of evidence that it's a choice. The fact is, we don't know yet.

Comment: There are certain scientific studies which cast doubt on the idea that change is possible.  I've never actually read any of those studies.  But simply hearing about them has put doubts in my mind.  The last paragraph of your quote has helped calm my doubts.  Thank you very much.  Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: There's [plenty of evidence that sexuality is innate](http://nymag.com/news/features/33520/), and is [fixed well before birth](http://isbn.nu/0720613094). I don't know much about JONAH, but it looks like they've thrown their hat in the ring with NARTH, who are known pseudoscientific frauds.

Comment: @TRiG: In your last comment, you linked to an article in New York Magazine, which is non-peer-reviewed. There's a lot of junk science in today's world. Please cite only sources [considered reliable for backing biomedical assertions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Identifying_reliable_sources_%28medicine%29). With love,

Comment: @tealhill. It is, however, more accessible than *Born Gay? The psychobiology of sex orientation*, albeit somewhat less detailed.

Comment: @TRiG: Plenty of evidence contradicts the idea that sexuality is innate. See http://enwp.org/Environment_and_sexual_orientation for starters. But [an APA pamphlet](http://snipurl.com/252kynp) states that, in sum, we still don't know what determines sexuality: "Alhough much research has examined the possible genetic, hormonal, developmental, social, and cultural influences on sexual orientation, no findings have emerged that permit scientists to conclude that sexual orientation is determined by any particular factor or factors. Many think nature and nurture both play complex roles[...]."

Comment: @tealhill. I think it's fair to say that the science is complex. I think it's also fair to say that the sentence in the answer *There is not a shred of evidence that anyone is born gay* is absolutely and entirely false, which is why I downvoted this answer. There is, in fact, quite a lot of evidence. It's complex, and disputed, and nowhere near settled, but it certainly does exist, and pretending it doesn't helps noone. This answer is absolutely and clearly wrong, and it's a disgrace that it's attracted as many upvotes as it has.

Comment: @TRiG:  I, too, have indeed never seen a shred of convincing evidence that anyone is born gay.  I've seen evidence that perhaps genetics has _some_ effect on sexual orientation.  But I've never seen any evidence that genetic influence is the _only_ determinant.

Comment: @tealhill. Have you looked for such evidence? Are you qualified to judge it? And who said it was all about genetics? Prenatal hormone levels and other factors of the womb environment may also have a role to play. "Born gay" != "it's all in the genes". That's your oversimplification. Did you look up the book I linked to above?

Comment: @TRiG:  i have never seen a shred of convincing evidence that genetic influences, hormonal influences, and/or any in-womb influences are the sole determinants of sexual orientation.  you are welcome to point me to some free full-text online sources that imply otherwise.  am i qualified to judge them?  who knows.  and to answer your last question, i have neither purchased nor read the book you linked to above.

Comment: @tealhill. I'm not aware that anyone here has said that *anything* is the *sole* determinant of sexual orientation.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, [JONAH has been the subject of allegations of malpractice & sexual abuse](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/abuse-victims-advocates-turn-to-the-internet/2012/03/16/gIQA7Vs9NS_story.html). Before that even gets into the picture, however, the entire idea that homosexuality is a curable ailment is highly suspect. From [Psychology Today](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/side-effects/201108/curing-homosexuality):

> "Most professional psychologists view reparative therapy skeptically,
>   to say the least. In 2007 the American Psychological Association
>   assembled a task force to study the effectiveness of this approach.
>   After spending two years sifting through the available research—it
>   evaluated eighty-three studies dating back to 1960—the group concluded
>   that there was scant evidence that sexual orientation could be
>   changed. What's more, it found that attempting to do so could cause
>   depression and suicidal tendencies among patients. Based on these
>   findings, in 2009 the APA voted to repudiate reparative therapy by a
>   margin of 125 to 4."

At best, they are giving false hope to people who really need help accepting their sexuality.  At worst they are actively exploiting and abusing those people. Highly suspect.

Comment: Is this an answer to the [empirical](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16294/do-jonah-and-similar-organizations-provide-useful-help-to-jews-attracted-to-the/16319#comment34137_16294) read of the question? If it is, I find it odd that you would answer an empirical question with allegations and indecisiveness.

Comment: I answered for both of the two options you present in your comment: 

1. They do not 'cure' gay people, as that is impossible
2. Their aims are not worthwhile as "[a]t best, they are giving false hope to people who really need help accepting their sexuality. At worst they are actively exploiting and abusing those people."

Comment: 1) Anyone who thinks it is _impossible_ to change someone's sexual preferences is being as silly as anyone who thinks it _must_ be possible. We're looking for data about JONAH's progress, not speculation. 2) Don't you see the assumptions you have latent in that sentence?? If you think what they need is help accepting their sexuality, then of course this system is pointless! You should answer by explaining __why__ that is what they need! That will contribute to the axiological discussion; this is just your declarations. -1 until you edit.

Comment: @Double AA - I question your definition of empirical. You asked if JONAH (and similar organizations) "accomplish something good." If you're going to criticize a very good and appropriate answer to your question as being non-empirical, the burden is upon you to first empirically define "accomplish something good."

Comment: @Shemmy You misunderstand. The empirical version of my question was if JONAH accomplishes what they set out to do, ie do they actually successfully change anyones sexual preferences? "something good" is inherently an axiological phrase.

Comment: @Double AA -  "Silly?!" You criticised a rational response as "silly?" That's kind of strange. Plus, why did the so-called empirical version of your question get changed to something axiological?

Comment: @Shemmy Where do I decry axiological discussion? And when are absolute factual non-trivial statements not silly?

Comment: @Shemmy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3422/discussion-between-double-aa-and-shemmy)

Comment: @DoubleAA If the scientific opinion of trained psychologists formed by two years of research doesn't hold enough weight for me to say that 'cures' are impossible, then it's unfortunately apparent that you are not going to take any level of proof.

Comment: @YaakovKuperman Absolutely! I will not take any 'proof' in either direction. Luckily, that's not what the question asked for, or else I would have voted to close it.

Comment: You said I wasn't answering the question well enough.  When I pointed out that I was answering all your questions you downvoted me and said (to summarize)'You should answer by explaining why that is what they need!' I provided ample proof to my assertions.  Now that I've pointed that out, you're saying that irrelevant because the question wasn't asking for that.  Please explain where my answer has any objective shortcomings.

Comment: The question was not asking if it is possible to change one's sexual preferences (which is what your post answers). It is either asking if JONAH has successfully done so ('empirical'), or it is asking if changing someone's sexual preferences would be a good thing ('axiological'). You answer neither EXCEPT through your implicit assertion that the latter would be a bad thing (based on "people who really need help accepting their sexuality" as opposed to people living without accepting, etc.). Please explain why it would be a bad thing, and don't just assert it.

Comment: To reiterate - I answer both your claims.  "Empirically" JONAH has never 'cured' a gay person, as that's impossible as per qualified experts.  Since their entire premise is faulty and they have been accused of various types of malpractice and abuse, they're not doing something that would be qualified as 'good'.  You're getting stuck on my description of a preferred treatment for these people as 'accepting their sexuality'.  I think that this is the only other treatment to give a closeted homosexual and that however you view it, it is not at all part of my main point or deserving of a downvote.

Comment: I don't see how your citation of certain psychologists tells us the extent to which these organizations are successful at their stated goals. || If I ignore your final description (per your request), where do you discuss if and why changing someone's sexual preferences is a bad thing?

Comment: My well-source point is that JONAH is based on a false premise that you can do that sort of therapy.  This gets back to my point that if you aren't going to accept a long running scientific study by recognized experts as basis for my assertions, then you're just dismissing my point of view a priori and won't take any evidence at all. Please take an objective P.O.V. instead of downvoting me because you don't like what I have to say.

Comment: I don't know how your point is objective. I downvoted you because you didn't answer the question, not because of any personal thoughts on the matter. I don't know how else to explain my point to you except as I have above. I'm sorry if you didn't follow, but there is not much else I can do.

Comment: FYI It seems the question has been updated.

Comment: To be clear, "Reparative Therapy" is not a catch-all term for everything that the pseudoscientific frauds at NARTH, JONAH, Exodus and the like do. "Reparative Therapy" is one particular therapeutic model, which is highly flawed. It's heavily promoted by NARTH, and has been dropped by Exodus. I don't know to what extent JONAH uses it. Either way, to say that reparative therapy is worthless is not in itself to say that everything these organisations do is worthless.

Comment: @DoubleAA is making some absolutely excellent points, if you feel that they are not, please read and re-read them until you get it. -1

Answer (score 0):

[NARTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Association_for_Research_&_Therapy_of_Homosexuality) published in "[The Journal of Human Sexuality](http://www.narth.com/menus/journal.html)" a landscape review of over 600 peer reviewed studies that supports the science that people can and do change sexual orientation. As one of the major organizations involved in this work, JONAH has a proven track record of success in helping men and women overcome unwanted same-sex attractions. Innumerable individuals who have utilized the resources of JONAH have achieved their goals.

Comment: A link would be most useful.

Comment: This sounds like an excerpt from a press release.

Comment: -1, please provide at least one actual source. You link to a the journal's site, but not to an article.

Comment: Rav Aron Feldman cites this journal in 'eye of the storm', I have received a copy of the source and read it my self. It shares statistics that suggest that homosexual relationships are less about a bond between people and more about the sexual act. This data was taken a while back, so one could argue that the sample size was too small. Rav Feldman also cites an instance of a man who had this issue and who is now married to a woman who helped him through it with children. He concedes that some people who seek help may not find it and provides advice, including a personal letter to gay Jews.

Comment: Here: http://www.unav.es/icf/main/top/diciembre09/Narth_What-research-shows-homosexuality.pdf