# Is a homosexual male obligated to try everything to change his orientation?

Tags: halacha, medicine, sexuality, sin, men-male

Given that homosexual relations is a biblical sin, I would like to know if a Jewish male homosexual has an obligation to try to change his sexual orientation (as opposed to just not acting on his homosexual impulses)?

I am aware that there is considerable controversy over organizations like JONAH ([related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16294/do-jonah-and-similar-organizations-successfully-help-those-with-same-gender-attr)), my question is not whether or **not** to use a specific organization or technique, but rather if there is an obligation to use any and all possible means to change.

Comment: Why would you think he needs to change? Pru urvu?

Comment: How posekim answer this halachic question may depend on their understanding of the empirical question of whether, and under what circumstances, such a change is possible.

Comment: They only problem would be hirhurim

Comment: @IsaacMoses I can't recall the exact language of the gemarah but there is an indication that nearly everyone is guilty of some form of lashon horah at some point, but that does not preclude us from trying daily to avoid speaking it, even if we fail.

Comment: @user6641, I don't think there's any question at all whether people with an inclination toward a particular sin are required to resist that inclination. Your question is about whether they are required to "try everything" to remove the inclination. The analogue would be some sort of therapy that removes the urge to gossip.

Comment: @IsaacMoses isn't that exactly what mussar is?

Comment: @user6641 I'm confused about what you mean by both "try anything" and "mussar." The former sounds a great deal broader (e.g. including things like hormone therapy, I guess) than the latter. If the question is "should people in class X engage in mussar?" then anyone who's an advocate of mussar will say "yes, of course," regardless of what X is.

Comment: ... or are you saying that specifically in the case of L"H, "try anything" would be mussar, because mussar is sufficient to completely remove the urge to speak L"H? If so, I think that's another empirical question that different posekim might have different understandings of.

Comment: @IsaacMoses the way I see it is as a difference of degree. Most people don't identify as baale lashon hara, that's just something they happen to do, so for them mussar may (or may not) be sufficient. Someone who's identity is bound to a particular sin may need to consider a broader array of tactics to combat it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't think your first comment is on the mark. There may be a Halachic imperative to do anything possible even if nothing is possible. Then the imperative  just doesn't force you to do anything.

Comment: @user6641 Their identity is not bound to a sin. That is a gross misunderstanding of what it means to "come out". Homosexuals don't identify as Baalei Mishkav Zechur; they just realize that it's harder for them to avoid it then for you or me. Are alcoholics binding themselves to sin by recognizing they have a predisposition to a certain desire? [The first step of AA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-step_program#Twelve_Steps) is admission!

Comment: @DoubleAA alcoholics or anyone with an addiction certainly seems to be binding their identity to a behavior as "I'm Bob and I am addicted to 'X'" would imply. Society and medical science seem to determine what falls in most of those categories. I believe my question could apply to "I'm Bob and I'm an adulterer" just as well, only AFAIK nobody claims that to be an unalterable condition, even though there may be biological predisposition (as well as increased yetzer hara - mayim genuvim yimtaku) to it.

Comment: @use Its not binding it to sin though! Someone who refuses to sit in the back of the shul because he has a yetzer hara for talking: is his choice to do that (everyone knows why) embarrassing or praiseworthy? We must understand ourselves to be able to face challenges correctly. One of the most important parts of knowing that someone else is gay is that you don't make them feel ABSOLUTELY TERRIBLE by trying to set them up on Shiduchim and having them refuse or be humiliated. Other than that, it doesn't affect my relationship with anyone I know who is gay who isn't in a active sexual relationship

Comment: I don't envy that they have this _nisayon_ in life, but I am truly envious of the Olam HaBa they can earn by succeeding. It's not embarrassing that God gave them this challenge as we don't choose what challenges God gives us.

Comment: @DoubleAA Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19756/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 4):

While not a direct answer to your question, I think you can glean insights from [Rav Twersky's response to a "gay forum"](http://www.syaross.org/misc/gaypanel/twersky.html).

From this, I infer that his main focus is that the Torah describes homosexuality as an abomination - "to'evah". This is a very strong term that the Torah rarely uses. Rav Twersky delves into the importance of what true Halachic commitment means. In brief, I infer from the article that his opinion would be that yes, there is a halachic requirement to change one's orientation.

Comment: As R Twersky says, "If you're talking about k'vod shomayim, one does what is right, what is calibrated for k'vod shomayim, and it doesn't make any difference, any other cheshbonos. It doesn't make a difference what anyone else thinks. If it's the right thing for kvod shomayim, if it expresses what should be said and what should be expressed for kvod shomayim, it doesn't make a difference what anyone else thinks. Sof davar hakol nishma — it doesn't make a difference what anyone else thinks." It is thus by his ruling that I encourage everyone to avoid reading that response/chillulhashem.

Comment: Can you please explain EXACTLY what lead you to that conclusion. Also, please differentiate between homosexual conduct which is prohibited or simply "being" homosexual.

Comment: @Gavriel - I'm uncertain if you are addressing me or DoubleAA. I think that Rav Twersky states that there is no difference between the two. I.e. - thoughts / orientation eventually leads to conduct. This is true in numerous areas of halacha, which is why the rabbis have built "fences" to prevent people from incorrect thoughts. You are welcome to disagree with Rav Twersky's or my opinion.

Comment: Note that there being a requirement to do so does not imply that there is any way to do so.

Comment: why would  there be a requirement,if there si no way of doing so,that is torture?(at least in this topic)

Comment: @Eagel _ I think you meant to address DoubleAA's question. But, as I got it, my take is that it depends on your definition of "torture". As far as I know, conversion therapy does not involve any form of physical torturing. It is psychological and emotional training. Yes, it can be stressful as any type of emotional stress would be even w/o a professional psychologist as mediator. But, I don't think that's considered torture. Within the realm of numerous things in halacha, a person makes tremendous sacrifices and forgoes many of life's "pleasures".

Comment: @DanF yes I did  address DoubleAA .And off course we can never do all the things in the law,but there is offering and repenting.But there must be a real solution.

Comment: @Eagel I think the "real" solution that's available is conversion therapy. I don't know if there are alternatives. Unfortunately, there are numerous problems in current Jewish society that are not yet handled or addressed sufficiently; I have one, in particular, that's a big hot unaddressed issue on my mind - separate story. In some, we are improving, slowly. Others, we can best fight and educate whom we can.

Comment: @DanF that's a big hot unaddressed issue on my mind ?

Comment: @Eagel Loud ear-damaging music at Jewish affairs is the issue I am referring to. Few are addressing the problem or acknowledging that it **is** a problem.

Comment: @DanF Jewish affairs,I dunno ,there are like two jewish affairs in my city

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35481/discussion-between-danf-and-eagel).